# How I separate the host example.com from an e-mail address like user@example.com using PHP?

Tags: php, email

I need to get the host example.com from an e-mail address like user@example.com using PHP?

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: PHP string functions it the cornerstone of the language. One who want to use PHP indeed have to learn it at least briefly: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

```
<?php
$str = 'user@gmail.com';

// positive limit
print_r(explode('@', $str, 2));

?>

//output

Array
(
    [0] => user
    [1] => gmail.com
)
```

Answer (score 2):

`split()` is deprecated; `explode()` is the way to go:

```
$parts = explode("@", $email);
echo "Name: " . $parts[0] . "\n";
echo "Host: " . $parts[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```
$email = 'user@gmail.com';
$array = explode('@', $email);
var_dump($array);
```

Output:

```
array(
  0 => 'user',
  1 => 'gmail.com'

)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
$name = 'someone@gmail.com';
$result = strstr($name, '@');
echo $result;
```

return's @gmail.com

or

```
$name = 'someone@gmail.com';
$result = substr(strstr($name, '@'), 1);
echo $result;
```

return's gmail.com